# Есть ли аналог isInEditMode для xml-разметки?

Tags: android

В кастомном вью я могу использовать [InEditMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#isInEditMode()).

А что если мне надо разные значения атрибутов для "дизайна" и для запущенного приложения?

К примеру. У меня есть `TextView`. Я хочу, чтобы при просмотре в Android Studio на вкладке "Design" у элемента был атрибут `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf` заданный `@id/view1`, а в запущенном приложении - `@id/view2`.

Порой бывает нужно увидеть несколько вьюх одновременно. Вьюхи распологаются на одном и том же месте, в приложении одновременно видно только одно. Но во время разработки хочется видеть обе вьюхи.

Попробовал использовать `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf` и `tools:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf` одновременно. Но значение `app` "перебивает" значение из `tools`.

Comment: Возможно все дело в порядке следования атрибутов с префиксами `app` и `tools`? Покажите разметку.

Comment: Не, я пробовал их переставлять, не помогло. View - простой TextView, https://pastebin.com/gVNeXiKu, https://pastebin.com/BvQraAw4